# is there a way to "watch" for new database table inserts using rake task?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I have rufus scheduler and i was planning to watch my schedules table for new schedules. Is there a way to do that? something like:

```
schedule.every "1m" do
  #check for new entries in database
end
```

**ANSWERED**

```
scheduler.every '1m' do
  #check for new stuff in the database
  newest_jobs = Schedule.all_cron_jobs.select{ |x| x.created_at > 1.minute.ago } - all_schedules_with_cron
  unless newest_jobs.empty?
    newest_jobs.each do |new_job|
      scheduler.every new_job.cron_string do
        job.call
      end
    end
  end
end
```

jobs.call is a call to delayed job to queue that schedule. So basically, get the newest schedules, and call rufus on them to put the jobs on queue every time the cron matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `created_at` column on the table to check for new entries since you last checked.

```
last_checked = 1.minute.ago
schedule.every "1m" do
  new_entries = Schedule.where(['created_at >= ?', last_checked])
  last_checked = Time.now

  # deal with entries here.
end
```

You could improve this by minimising the gap between `last_checked` cycles even more.

Would you not be better to use an observer on the model instead of this? Guarantees no misses due to timing issues.

Comment: any suggestion to go about this is good. what observer are you talking about? like an after save? was supposed to be that but we only needed one thread. this is in relation to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495946/rufus-scheduler-multiple-instances-or-just-one

Comment: If you want to distribute this work amongst multiple machines, it would be best to use a queue and worker system such as Resque. Using a cron-like setup is pretty crude.

Comment: oh we're using workers with delayed job already. the scheduler actually calls delayed job on the scheduleable when it occurs. say i have a cron every Monday, on Monday, scheduler will create a delayed_job on that day and it will be included in the queue. adding the scheduler itself to delayed job seems inefficient...right?

Comment: I see. I was suggesting that you should create a delayed_job job every time a schedule is created, but I guess you might be doing something with more than one record at a time.